# how to set Run configure arguments of a java class other then in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

we have java class for data ingestion from xml to database using hibernate,
which we have to run as run configuration and it takes two arguments

```
1. data/ingest/xml
2. -dtd DTD/sample-dtd.xml
```

first argument is a `xml` files folder and second is `dtd` , I am trying to find a way where I don't have to set this arguments in eclipse but may be from `.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Using properties file is infact a very good approach when you are using constants and you don't want to re-compile your code just because (lets say) the path of your file changes.

To configure to use properties, you first make a properties file (lets call it myApp.properties)

```
#My application properties #####
prop1_key=property_value
ingestion_xml_path=data/ingest/xml
dtd_xml_path=DTD/sample-dtd.xml
```

Next we want to read these properties in your application. You can do that by using the Properties class of Java

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;
try {
    // be sure to give correct path to the properties file
    input = new FileInputStream("myApp.properties");
    // load a properties file
    prop.load(input);

    // get the property value by the keys we defined in the properties
    String ingestion_path = prop.getProperty("ingestion_xml_path")

    ...// Now you can use this value ...

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```